# Mysterious C function calling

Tags: c, function-call

I have this code:

```
int indexOf(const char *array[], char *e)
{
     printf("inside: %d\n",(int)sizeof(array));
/* ... */
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    const char *a[] = {";", ",", ":", "==", ":="};
    char *b = "==";
    printf("outside: %d\n",(int)sizeof(a));
    int d = indexOf(a,b);
/* ... */
}
```

And this is the output:

```
outside: 40
inside: 8
```

Why output is not the same? Any help, please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The array decays into a pointer to it's first element when passed to a function. The `sizeof` from the function yields the size of the pointer on your implementation. You could have declared it:

```
int indexOf(const char **array, char *e)
```

You will probably want to pass the length as a separate parameter.

#### EDIT

> What I'm trying is to avoid to pass the size as a parameter.

In that case you could mark the end of the array with a `NULL`

```
const char *a[] = {";", ",", ":", "==", ":=", NULL};
```

That way in the function you will know where it ends.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't resolve it. The output continue being the same.

Comment: @user1015100 I didn't say it will solve it. At the end of the post I said: *You will probably want to pass the length as a separate parameter*

Comment: Your answer doesn't change the output.

Comment: Is impossible to calculate the length inside the function? (Sorry, I'm reading but you answered while I was typing and I haven't read you. Indeed, i'm spanish and my english is far from perfect).

Comment: @user1015100 Declare your function like this: `int indexOf(const char **array, char *e, size_t size)` and call it with the size.

Comment: What I'm trying is to avoid to pass the size as a parameter. Thanks for your fast answers.

Comment: @pamojarpan See my edit. Perhaps an argv-style array will do ?

Comment: @pamojarpan - Passing the size as a parameter is the correct thing to do. Ending the array with `NULL` is the cause of all kinds of security problems in the C standard library.

Comment: @Brendan Long Nah. strings are like *totally safe*. :)

Comment: @BrendanLong Firstly, I'm not a C programmer. How ending the array with NULL could cause problems? Is '\0', for example, safer?

Comment: @pamojarpan - `'\0'` is exactly the same thing as `0`. Ending an array with `NULL` is very easy to get wrong, and passing the size is very easy. What happens if your `NULL` gets overwritten? Not possible? That's what they all say.

Comment: @BrendanLong Thanks, I will pass the size in another functions of this program. In this case I use a read only array (*const*), so NULL as ending is not a problem, right?

Comment: @pamojarpan - My advice is to always pass the size. If you want to do the `NULL` ending thing, it will work *as long as you get it right*. So be careful.